# Hortonworks ODBC driver does not apply server-site property

Tags: hadoop, odbc, microstrategy

I've installed ODBC Driver from http://hortonworks.com/hdp/addons/
and configured to use my Hive Server 2 on HDP installation.
I'm using Microstrategy Microstrategy Analytics Desktop to run queries. It works fine, until I'm trying to use server side property.

I've configured my ODBC Data Source Administrator/System DSN/Hortoworks Hive ODBC Driver Setup/Advanced Options/Setver Side Properties as follows:

```
SSP_mapred.job.queue.name = pr
SSP_tez.queue.name = pr
```

But in Applications on HDP I can see that MSTR is using 'default' queue instead of pr.

What am I doing wrong? In Installation guide for the Hortonworks driver (as well as for Simba Driver) property is calld: SSP_mapred.queue.names=myQueue but it doesnt work as well..
Is there any place I can see the log of this connection and check if the properties are sent to the asever at all?

Regrds 
Pawel

Comment: maybe is just the missing `s` in .names

Comment: Just to clarify, are you only using the properties you've defined above, or have you also tried SSP_mapred.queue.names? As @mucio mentioned, did it have the the s in .names?

Comment: I have tried both - SSP_mapred.queue.names as pointed in Users Guide and mapred.job.queue.name and SSP_tez.queue.name which are properties I actually need. Is there any possibility to check if connector sends these properties to the Hive Server?